# Kotlin - extensible type-safe builders

Tags: kotlin, factory, builder

I want to be able to create a custom builder-pattern DSL-type thing, and I want the ability to create new components in a clean and type-safe way. How can I hide the implementation details required for creating and extending such a builder-pattern?

The Kotlin docs give something like the following example:

```
html {
    head {
        title {+"XML encoding with Kotlin"}
    }
    body {
        h1 {+"XML encoding with Kotlin"}
        p  {+"this format can be used as an alternative markup to XML"}

        a(href = "http://kotlinlang.org") {+"Kotlin"}

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Here, all of the possible "elements" are predefined and implemented as functions that also return objects of the corresponding types. (eg. the `html` function returns an instance of the `HTML` class)

Each function is defined so that it adds itself to its parent context's object as a child.

Suppose someone wanted to create a new element type `NewElem` usable as `newelem`. They would have to do something cumbersome such as:

```
class NewElem : Element() {
    // ...
}

fun Element.newelem(fn: NewElem.() -> Unit = {}): NewElem {
    val e = NewElem()
    e.fn()
    this.addChild(e)
    return e
}
```

every time.

*Is there a clean way to hide this implementation detail?*

I want to be able to create a new element by simply extending `Element` for example.

I do not want to use reflection if possible.

## Possibilities I Tried

My main problem is coming up with a clean solution. I thought of a couple other approaches that didn't pan out.

#### 1) Create new elements with a function call that returns a function to be used in the builder style such as:

```
// Pre-defined
fun createElement(...): (Element.() -> Unit) -> Element

// Created as
val newelem = createElement(...)

// Used as
body {
    newelem {
        p { +"newelem example" }
    }
}
```

There are obvious downsides to this, and I don't see a clear way to implement it either - probably would involve reflection.

#### 2) Override the invoke operator in companion object

```
abstract class Element {
    companion object {
        fun operator invoke(build: Element.() -> Unit): Element {
            val e = create()
            e.build()
            return e
        }
        abstract fun create(): Element
    }
}

// And then you could do
class NewElem : Element() {
    companion object {
        override fun create(): Element {
            return NewElem()
        }
    }
}

Body {
    NewElem {
        P { text = "NewElem example" }
    }
}
```

It is unfortunately not possible to enforce "static" functions to be implemented by subclasses in a type-safe way.

Also, companion objects aren't inherited, so the invoke on subclasses wouldn't work anyway.

And we again run into problems about adding children elements to the correct context, so the builder doesn't actually build anything.

#### 3) Override the invoke operator on Element types

```
abstract class Element {
    operator fun invoke(build: Element.() -> Unit): Element {
        this.build()
        return this
    }
}

class NewElem(val color: Int = 0) : Element()

Body() {
    NewElem(color = 0xff0000) {
        P("NewElem example")
    }
}
```

This *might* have worked, except for when you immediately try to invoke on the object created by the constructor call, the compiler cannot tell that the lambda is for the "invoke" call and tries to pass it into the constructor.

This can be fixed by making something slightly less clean:

```
operator fun Element.minus(build: Element.() -> Unit): Element {
    this.build()
    return this
}

Body() - {
    NewElem(color = 0xff0000) - {
        P("NewElem example")
    }
}
```

But yet again, adding children elements to the parent elements isn't actually possible without reflection or something similar, so the builder still doesn't actually build anything.

#### 4) Calling `add()` for sub-elements

To try to fix the issue of the builder not actually building anything, we could implement an `add()` function for sub-elements.

```
abstract class Element {
    fun add(elem: Element) {
        this.children.add(elem)
    }
}

Body() - {
    add(NewElem(color = 0xff0000) - {
        add(P("NewElem red example"))
        add(P("NewElem red example 2"))
    })
    add(NewElem(color = 0x0000ff) - {
        add(P("NewElem blue example"))
    })
}
```

But this is obviously not clean and is just deferring the cumbersome-ness to the usage side instead of the implementation side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that isn't the most elegant, but it is passable and works the way I would want it to.

It turns out that if you override an operator (or create any extension function for that matter) *inside* a class, it has access to its parent context.

So I overrode the unary `+` operator

```
abstract class Element {
    val children: ArrayList<Element> = ArrayList()

    // Create lambda to add children
    operator fun minus(build: ElementCollector.() -> Unit): Element {
        val collector = ElementCollector()
        collector.build()
        children.addAll(collector.children)
        return this
    }
}

class ElementCollector {
    val children: ArrayList<Element> = ArrayList()

    // Add child with unary + prefix
    operator fun Element.unaryPlus(): Element {
        this@ElementCollector.children.add(this)
        return this
    }
}

// For consistency
operator fun Element.unaryPlus() = this
```

This allows me to create new elements and use them like this:

```
class Body : Element()
class NewElem : Element()
class Text(val t: String) : Element()

fun test() =
        +Body() - {
            +NewElem()
            +NewElem() - {
                +Text("text")
                +Text("elements test")
                +NewElem() - {
                    +Text("child of child of child")
                }
                +Text("it works!")
            }
            +NewElem()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unavoidable to add some sort of a helper function for each `Element` subclass you create, but their implementation can be simplified with generic helper functions.

---

For example, you can create a function that performs the setup call and adds the new element to the parent, then you only have to call into this function and create an instance of your new element:

```
fun <T : Element> Element.nest(elem: T, fn: T.() -> Unit): T {
    elem.fn()
    this.addChild(elem)
    return elem
}

fun Element.newElem(fn: NewElem.() -> Unit = {}): NewElem = nest(NewElem(), fn)
```

---

Alternatively, you could create that instance via reflection to simplify even further, but since you've stated you'd like to avoid it, this will probably seem unnecessary:

```
inline fun <reified T : Element> Element.createAndNest(fn: T.() -> Unit): T {
    val elem = T::class.constructors.first().call()
    elem.fn()
    this.addChild(elem)
    return elem
}

fun Element.newElem(fn: NewElem.() -> Unit = {}) = createAndNest(fn)
```

---

These still leave you with having to declare a factory function with the appropriate header, but this is the only way to achieve the syntax that the HTML example achieves, where a `NewElem` can be created with its own `newElem` function.